# IIS URL Rewriting rule - exclude ALL files and a specific path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I want to create a URL rewrite rule that adds a `/` on URLs that don't have one so for example:

`www.domain.com/news/latest` will get redirected to `www.domain.com/news/latest/`

The rule below does exactly that, but the problem I am having is two fold:

1. This rewrite rule is getting applied to things like image files.
   So For example `domain.com/globalassets/icons/image.svg` gets changed to `domain.com/globalassets/icons/image.svg/` causing a 404 its not happening with CSS files which is strange, maybe because I am adding them using the  `RegisterBundles` method in MVC?
2. This is a ASP.NET MVC based website using a CMS (episerver) so I want to ignore any redirects in the Admin area so I added a second rule, but again its doing this to the CSS and images breaking the admin area.

This is what I have got so far, can anyone help me get this rule working correctly?

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>

      <rule name="Exclude Slash Episerver " stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^episerver/" />
        <action type="None" />
      </rule>

      <rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/" />
      </rule>

    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common SEO rewrite rules for IIS such as this one are [documented here](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension).

In particular, with the **Trailing Slash** rule you are missing the [`logicalGrouping="MatchAll"` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rule-conditions):

> Conditions are defined within a `<conditions>` collection of a rewrite rule. This collection has an attribute called `logicalGrouping` that controls how conditions are evaluated. If a rule has conditions, then the rule action is performed only if rule pattern is matched and:
>
> - All conditions were evaluated as true, provided that **logicalGrouping="MatchAll"** was used.
> - At least one of the conditions was evaluated as true, provided that **logicalGrouping="MatchAny"** was used.

Without this setting, it is adding a trailing slash to your file names because it is matching when *any* of your negated rules match rather than *all* of them.

---

The entire **Trailing Slash** rule from the above link is:

```
<rule name="Trailing Slash" stopProcessing="true"> 
    <match url="(.*[^/])$" /> 
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false"> 
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="WebResource.axd" negate="true" /> 
    </conditions> 
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" /> 
</rule>
```